# Android - Metodo setOnMarkerClickListener ejecutar al segundo clic

Tags: android, onclick

Quiero saber si se puede realizar el método `setOnMarkerClickListener`, pero que realiza la tarea programada al segundo clic.

```
 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {



                }
            });
```

EJ: tengo un marcador de google maps, el cual muestra informacion, quiero que al presionar una vez muestre la información, y si apretó dos veces me envié a una activity que ya tengo creada.

Comment: Si que se puede. Te pediría que editases tu pregunta añadiendo código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora para que podamos ver donde te has equivocado o lo que te falta para llegar a lo que quieres.

Comment: Fue de ayuda lo que public en mi respuesta @Fernandobrito

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para esto puedes usar el mismo método `onMarkerClick()` pero mediante un handler puedes validar si transcurre por ejemplo mas de un segundo y medio entre click, es un click si ambos click ocurren en menos de es un doble click:

Declara una variable a nivel de clase:

```
boolean doubleClick = false;
```

Esta sería la forma de detectar un click o doble:

```
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                if (doubleClick) {

                    //DOBLE CLICK 
                    // ABRE ACTIVITY

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtraActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {

                    //UN CLICK
                    // Muestra información

                    doubleClick = true;
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            doubleClick = false;
                        }
                    }, 1500); //1.5 segundos
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.